# WDS "No response" only when notify and wait for approval

Tags: deployment, wds

I have a WDS server setup for use with MDT2010, and everything was working fine until this morning.  Now, whenever I try to boot from LAN, I get an error:

```
Downloaded WDSNBP...

Architecture: x64
WDSNBP started using DHCP Referral.
Contacting Server: 10.50.10.12 (Gateway: 0.0.0.0)
No response from Windows Deployment Services server.
Launching pxeboot.com
```

My PXE Response Policy setting on the WDS is set to this:

```
[ ] Do not respond to any client computer
[ ] Respond only to known client computers
[o] Respond to all (known and unknown) client computers
    [X] For unknown clients, notify administrator and respond after approval
```

The odd thing is that if I clear the approval option (so any computer gets a response) it works fine.

I have delegated permissions on the AD OU to the computer object WDS is running on, but that doesn't seem to have helped.

As it works without approval, I can only assume my DHCP options are fine and this is some sort of AD permission problem.

(Server is Windows Server 2008 SP2)

Comment: I'm having the same problem except that When the approval option is cleared it doesn't work fine.

Comment: Same issue here, too. This just started happening today too, after a successful image. No idea what's changed.

Answer (score 1):

With that option ticked, all unkown computers should boot into WDS, but then be listed on the WDS server, awaiting approval, within **Pending Devices** .

Try extending the PXE response delay settings. It might be failing as the devices are not being approved within WDS, after requesting the boot.

Answer (score 0):

It was mentioned [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0efa6c4c-d10b-4bea-b5f6-66fe95c7e11b/no-response-from-windows-deployment-services-server?forum=itprovistadeployment) that you can remove the Mgmt folder in your WDS installation directory, replace it with an empty folder of the same name, and continue on error free.

Answer (score -3):

If you donot want to use WDS and wanna use PXE boot from SCCM instead, then apply option 67 in DHCP as 'smsboot\x64\pxeboot.com' instead of 'smsboot\x64\wdsnp.com'.

Thanks
ANoop

Comment: Im not sure that "use a completely different, more complex and more expensive tool" is a useful answer.